# knockoutjs - html in textarea

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs and need a way to display raw html inside a text area. Is is stored in my database as encoded html e.g.

```
&lt;object width="640" .....
```

But I want it to be displayed as

<object width="640"

for the user to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using `text` or `value` binding in `textarea` if you change it to `html` it will work as you needed:

```
<textarea data-bind="html: data"></textarea>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/qTRSX/

Comment: This will display the html properly within the textarea when reading from ko observable to textarea but not the other way.

Comment: displaying the data is fine but capturing it using html does not work

Comment: its does not show this mark up `<object width="640" />` how can i do it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your html is already escaped then you're all set, see [**demo**](https://tinker.io/e387e)